# Verify my solutuon: Prove that if $U$ is any non-principal ultraﬁlter on $\Bbb{N}$, then the ultrapower $\Bbb{N^N}/U$ has cardinality continuum

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic, natural-numbers

A few weeks ago, I had such homework exercise: Prove that if $U$ is any non-principal ultraﬁlter on $\Bbb{N}$, then the ultrapower $\Bbb{N^N}/U$ has cardinality continuum.
($\mathbb{N}$ stands for natural numbers.)

Solution shown by my professor was different than mine, so I want You to verify my solution: However, it works only assuming Continnum Hypothesis.

My solution:

It is obvious, that it has power less or equal continuum, because $\mathbb{N^N}$ has power continuum.

Assume it is countable. So, we can index its elements by natural numbers. Let $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots)$ - sequence of all element of that ultrapower $\mathbb{N^N}/U$. They can be written as sequences of natural numbers. Pick sequence of elements of ultrafilter $(u_1,u_2,u_3,\cdots)$ such that every coordinate belongs only to finitely many of these elements (it is possible bcs $U$ is nonprincipal).

Now construct a Cantor diagonal element (lets call it $C$) such that $C$ differs from $a_i$ exactly on coordinates belonging to $U_i$. It is possible, because every coordinate belongs only to finitely many $U_j$'s and there are infinitely many naturals.

$C$ belongs to our ultrapower $\mathbb{N^N}/U$ and is different from every element $\{a1,a2,a3,\cdots\}$ because Ui belongs to ultrafilter.

Hence, we have contradiction. That can't have cardinality $\aleph_0$.
More, assuming Continuum Hypothesis, it has power continuum.

Is it ok?

Comment: So you don't know how to use $\rm\LaTeX$?

Comment: MathJax is the same thing as LaTeX? I dont think so

Comment: It is based on $\rm\LaTeX$, yes. The syntax is very very similar. (There's no preamble, of course.) Just spend one or two minutes looking at the source code of some posts here, and you'll see.